# Are there any open-source or free softwares for covalent docking of multiple ligands?

Tags: software-recommendations, one-topic-per-answer, docking, autodock

I am currently screening more than 2000 compounds virtually on Vina, but I would like to perform covalent docking. Unfortunately, Vina's functionality is limited as its requires manual designation of the reactive atoms on the ligands. Is there any alternative that is free for academic purposes and suited for this sort of task?

Comment: You can have a look at AutoDock Vina, CovDock, or DOCKovalent. They all, if I undercorrectly, support covalent & non-covalent docking.

Comment: I gave my +1 a long time ago, but did the comment help answer your question? @HighPerformanceRangsiman why not write a full and complete answer?